# sum values of selected options based on data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

[View of My User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSXXO.jpg)

I have the above UI as you can see in the above images where user can select most preferred and least preferred option of the question. There are multiple questions like this. In my html you can see the tags value and data-id.

Actually what i want is, i want to sum values of selected options based on data-id.  Most preferred value will sum 3, least preferred value will sum 1 and the option which is not selected, will sum 2. I have atleast 20 questions and i want to get total sum based on selections corresponding to data-id.

Here is the html of one question below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="row-div mt-2">
      <div class="fix-div1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_left_1"
            name="Left_1"
            value="3"
            data-id="Recognition"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_left_1"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        Status symbol
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_right_1"
            name="Right_1"
            value="1"
            data-id="Recognition"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_right_1"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-div mt-2">
      <div class="fix-div1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_left_2"
            name="Left_1"
            value="3"
            data-id="Networking"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_left_2"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        An opportunity to be a part of various groups
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_right_2"
            name="Right_1"
            value="1"
            data-id="Networking"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_right_2"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-div mt-2">
      <div class="fix-div1">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_left_3"
            name="Left_1"
            value="3"
            data-id="KnowledgeSeeking"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_left_3"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        The challenges involved in the project
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input
            class="custom-control-input"
            type="radio"
            id="Q_1_rb_right_3"
            name="Right_1"
            value="1"
            data-id="KnowledgeSeeking"
          />
          <label
            for="Q_1_rb_right_3"
            class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"
          >
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the below function.. It is working fine, but it is giving only values of selected radios.. i also want to count 2 of option which is not selected.

```
var get_Networking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked").each(
  function () {
    sum_Networking += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  }
);

var get_Recognition = $(
  "input[type='radio'][data-id=Recognition]:checked"
).each(function () {
  sum_Recognition += Math.ceil($(this).val());
});

var get_KnowledgeSeeking = $(
  "input[type='radio'][data-id=KnowledgeSeeking]:checked"
).each(function () {
  sum_KnowledgeSeeking += Math.ceil($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Post your CSS also,  I dont know witch radio button is for what, make [mre]. never post pictures. You have a snippet here on SO. Put some effort in making a question and people will put some effort in answering.

Comment: i wasted my 30 mins to simply post this question and you are saying "put some effort"

Comment: wasted? OK then. you did waste it. I have an answer for you, but I have been working on on your other problems in code too, like the fact that you can select both `Most Preferred` and `Least Preferred` in same time, and your "calculation" is wrong with += . I will not post it now. I WASTED hour and half, first half even trying to decode your HTML to figure out what is what, and that WAS NOT the question. Why do you think so many people looked at your code and went away? Yeah put some some effort!

Comment: sorry bro... but i was also hurt by your words.. thanks for your precious time... i really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

First of all this: `i wasted my 30 mins to simply post this question and you are saying "put some effort"` is blunt disrispect to anyone trying to `waste` time to solve YOUR problem in there `FREE` time.

Read here how to make: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . It s required to help us help YOU. If your code is hard to understand people lose will to go thru it, and will just turn away, as seen in your example (36 people visited and counting). Solution to your problem is simple, and A LOT of those people could have solve it right away if your code was easy to understand and read.

Welcome to SO, this is how things go here.

As your question go, simple solution would be:

If your code reacts  only to `:checked` items, why don't simply set that variable to 2 if its empty (not checked)?

```
if (sum_Networking===""){
sum_Networking = 2;
}
if (sum_Recognition===""){
sum_Recognition = 2;
}
if (sum_KnowledgeSeeking===""){
sum_KnowledgeSeeking = 2;
}
```

The way you have set it it up now you can chose both `Most Preferred` and `Least Preferred` at same time and that is printing out `31`, so you don't even do "calculations" right.

As seen in this snippet:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
var sum_Networking = "";
var sum_Recognition = "";
var sum_KnowledgeSeeking = "";


  var get_Networking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked")
  get_Networking.each(function() { 
    sum_Networking += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

  var get_Recognition = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Recognition]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_Recognition += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

  var get_KnowledgeSeeking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=KnowledgeSeeking]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_KnowledgeSeeking += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

if (sum_Networking===""){
sum_Networking = 2;
}
if (sum_Recognition===""){
sum_Recognition = 2;
}
if (sum_KnowledgeSeeking===""){
sum_KnowledgeSeeking = 2;
}
 console.clear(); 
  console.log("sum_Networking: "+sum_Networking);
  console.log("sum_Recognition: "+sum_Recognition);
  console.log("sum_KnowledgeSeeking: "+sum_KnowledgeSeeking);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="row-div">

      <div class="fix-div1">
        Most Preferred

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">
        Least Preferred

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_1" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Recognition">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        Status symbol
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_1" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Recognition">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_2" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Networking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        An opportunity to be a part of various groups

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_2" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Networking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_3" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        The challenges involved in the project


      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_3" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>








</div>
```

To make sure no same row items can be chosen:

```
var data = $(this).data('id');
$("input[data-id='"+data+"']").prop("checked", false);
$(this).prop("checked", true);
```

Also change `+=` to `=`, if you want both values together, you usually should push them into array and deal with it later separately.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
var sum_Networking = "";
var sum_Recognition = "";
var sum_KnowledgeSeeking = "";


  var get_Networking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked")
  get_Networking.each(function() { 
    sum_Networking = Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

  var get_Recognition = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Recognition]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_Recognition = Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

  var get_KnowledgeSeeking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=KnowledgeSeeking]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_KnowledgeSeeking = Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

if (sum_Networking===""){
sum_Networking = 2;
}

if (sum_Recognition===""){
sum_Recognition = 2;
}

if (sum_KnowledgeSeeking===""){
sum_KnowledgeSeeking = 2;
}

var data = $(this).data('id');
$("input[data-id='"+data+"']").prop("checked", false);
$(this).prop("checked", true);

 console.clear(); 
  console.log("sum_Networking: "+sum_Networking);
  console.log("sum_Recognition: "+sum_Recognition);
  console.log("sum_KnowledgeSeeking: "+sum_KnowledgeSeeking);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
    <div class="row-div">

      <div class="fix-div1">
        Most Preferred

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">
        Least Preferred

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_1" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Recognition">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Recognition 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        Status symbol
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_1" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Recognition">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"> Recognition 1 </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_2" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Networking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">Networking  3</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        An opportunity to be a part of various groups

      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_2" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Networking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"> Networking 1</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row-div mt-2">

      <div class="fix-div1">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_3" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_left_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal"> KnowledgeSeeking 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="fix-div2">
        The challenges involved in the project


      </div>

      <div class="fix-div3">

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_3" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
          <label for="Q_1_rb_right_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">KnowledgeSeeking 1 </label>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>








</div>
```

Comment: width your approach this will sum 2 for each unchecked radio... which i dont want

Comment: I want only 2 when both radio buttons opposite to each other are not selected

Comment: it should sum for all questions.. not only just add 2 as there are lots of question